# speechRecognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition always returns false

Tags: swift, macos, sfspeechrecognizer

I've just updated to macOS 10.15.4 and every time I check if on-device speech recognition is available I get back false. This was working on 10.15.3.

```
speechRecognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition = true
print("supportsOnDeviceRecognition: \(String(describing: speechRecognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition))")
```

Anybody else seeing this? Are there any tricks to get this working again?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware `supportsOnDeviceRecognition` is locale dependent. If you init your `SFSpeechRecognizer` with the locale you are targeting, it will just start returning `true` assuming the locale Siri dictionary is downloaded on the device:

```swift
var unLocalizedSpeechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer.init()
// unLocalizedSpeechRecognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition is most likely `false`

// change en-US to whatever locale you are targeting
var localizedSpeechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer.init(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
// localizedSpeechRecognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition is most likely `true`
// if that local has been downloaded
```